# What the OS used by Samsung smart TV UE46ES6300S

Tags: smart-home, samsung-smartthings, smart-tv

I have an old Samsung smart TV UE46ES6300S (Model 2012) and I want to start developing a test Application for it.

I don't know which OS does my smart tv use, and which are the right tools to begin developing a simple HTML / JS / CSS Application for it.

Can anyone help to know the used used OS and the right tools to do it?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [TV model groups of the Samsung Smart TV developer site](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/specifications/tv-model-groups.html), the UE6300 series uses TV SDK 4.1, which is part of the "legacy" versions (newer versions use Tizen).

You can find the relevant software [here](https://developer.samsung.com/SmartTV/develop/tools/tv-extension/archive.html) (in the "Samsung TV SDK for Legacy Platform" section, selecting version 4.1.

Documentation is available [here](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/samsung-legacy-platform.html).

Since this is now an 8-year old "legacy" platform, don't expect too much support for it. I don't even know if you can even still publish apps using that platform.

Good luck!